# Why is this bootstrap drop down not working?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I know there are a lot of other similar questions and I have tried most of them, but nothing seems to work. It just does not expand to show the dropdown items.
I have included this in the head

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I have this

```
      <!-- DROPDOWN -->
    <div class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
            <img src="user.jpg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2"> 
                <strong> John W </strong> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li>                
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap 4 you need to use `data-toggle="dropdown"` rather than `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`.

```
<div class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1"
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
            <img src="user.jpg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2"> 
                <strong> John W </strong> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li>                
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

`data-bs-` was added to Bootstrap 5 only I believe.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Bootstrap 5.

Comment: Oh ok sorry it was tagged with bootstrap-4 so I assumed it was 4. 

Have you tried upgrading to 5.1.3 if you're on 5.0.1 now. 

Any console errors? Structure looks ok to me & works on codepen here: https://codepen.io/themelizeme/pen/KKvXQze

Comment: My mistake, wrong tag. I just managed to get it to work, thank you so much for trying to help me. I added aria-expanded="false", this script at the bottom <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> and this to <ul style="position: absolute; inset: auto auto 0px 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate(0px, -34px);" data-popper-placement="top-start">

Comment: Glad you got it working!